# Bash set a variable to cut of other variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, cut

I am trying to set a variable to the last thing in the path, but cant seem to figure out how to do it.  Right now, I have this, but it does not work:

```
path=echo pwd
last=echo $path | rev | cut -d / -f 1 | rev
```

So for example, if the path was ~/one/two/three, I would want last to be set to three.
Right now, whenever I run`echo $last`, all that is outputted is a blank line.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is called [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
last=$(pwd | rev | cut -d / -f 1 | rev)
echo "$last"
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable PWD is already filled, so you can do

```
last=${PWD##*/}
echo "${last}"
```

Comment: This syntax was new to me so I looked it up.  The braces ("{}") indicate shell expansion.  The `##` affects how that expansion happens.  What comes after the `##` is expanded to be a pattern and if the start of the expanded variable matches, it is deleted.  The double `##` means delete the longest matching part; a single `#` deletes the shortest part.  In this case, it's matching `*/`, so everything up to and including the last slash, leaving only the current directory name.  [There is more info here.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve same thing using simple awk command as well like below

```
last=`echo $PWD | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
echo $last
```

or using sed to strip the / first and then print the last dir name

```
last=`echo $PWD | sed 's/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}'`
echo $last
```